# How can I expose a Docker container port only to localhost so that it is also accessible via an ssh tunnel?

Tags: networking, docker, firewall, ssh-tunnel

Hopefully straightforward.  I know how to bind to the host only with

```
-p 127.0.0.1:$HOSTPORT:$CONTAINERPORT
```

The issue I'm encountering is that doing this preventing me from accessing the mapped host port over an ssh tunnel to the docker host.

Is there  way to do this without having to block the port upstream from the docker host somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the target of your ssh tunnel `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

```
ssh -L local-port:127.0.0.1:container-port docker-host
```

Would forward your `local-port` to `localhost:container-port` on `docker-host`. No need to expose the container port to the external network.

Comment: Thanks!  That did it.